# Draggable element in KineticJS that is "under" another?

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm wanting to have a template of a Magic-type card (but with an irregularly shaped art section), where a user can upload their own image and drag it around to place it, but the template will still be in the foreground.  I know with the EaselJS library, by default the "hit area" for clicks (to trigger things like click and drag) is only the visible pixels, so you could click "through" the transparent portion of a PNG and drag an element that is under it.  So I'm looking for something like that with KineticJS.  How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  [createHitRegion](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-pixel-detection-with-kineticjs/) is what I was looking for.